# Dataframe Normalization

Tags: r

I have a data frame with cols as follows:

name         age       hobbies
abc          10        video games,football,swimming

which i would like to convert this into some thing like this

name         age       hobbies
abc          10        videogames
abc          10        football
abc          10        swimming

[image: see this if you dont understand]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
cSplit(indt = df1, splitCols = "hobbies", sep = ",", direction = "long")
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    separate_rows(hobbies)
#  name   age  hobbies
#1   10 video    games
#2   10 video football
#3   10 video swimming
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = 10L, age = "video", 
hobbies = "games,football,swimming"), class = "data.frame", row.names = "abc")
```